# How can I exit Dask cleanly?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, contextmanager

I am starting Dask with a containerized LocalCluster but on closing the cluster and client I usually (but intermittently) receive a diverse range of exceptions - see for example the one below.

The cleanup code is:

```py
cluster.close()
client.close()
```

Is there an `Exception`-free way to close the Dask cluster, followed by closing the client(*)?

No solution I have found has resolved the issue for me. Surely it is possible to exit without `Exception`??

I would prefer a route that avoids use if the `with` statement, because the clean-up operation is embedded in a third-party class. If a context manager is the sole way to go, is it possible to call the relevant context manager directly without the `with`?

- PS Do I have it right that the cluster should be closed before the client (since the latter would presumably be required to achieve the former)? (Opinion seems to differ on the matter.)

```py
2023-05-22 20:59:26,890 - distributed.client - ERROR -
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 291, in connect
    comm = await asyncio.wait_for(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 481, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 511, in connect
    convert_stream_closed_error(self, e)
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 142, in convert_stream_closed_error
    raise CommClosedError(f"in {obj}: {exc.__class__.__name__}: {exc}") from exc
distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError: in <distributed.comm.tcp.TCPConnector object at 0x40deb132b0>: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/utils.py", line 742, in wrapper
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/client.py", line 1298, in _reconnect
    await self._ensure_connected(timeout=timeout)
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/client.py", line 1328, in _ensure_connected
    comm = await connect(
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 315, in connect
    await asyncio.sleep(backoff)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 655, in sleep
    return await future
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
2023-05-22 20:59:26 : ERROR : __exit__ : 768 :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 225, in read
    frames_nbytes = await stream.read_bytes(fmt_size)
tornado.iostream.StreamClosedError: Stream is closed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/client.py", line 1500, in _handle_report
    msgs = await self.scheduler_comm.comm.read()
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 241, in read
    convert_stream_closed_error(self, e)
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py", line 144, in convert_stream_closed_error
    raise CommClosedError(f"in {obj}: {exc}") from exc
distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError: in <TCP (closed) Client->Scheduler local=tcp://127.0.0.1:49712 remote=tcp://127.0.0.1:43205>: Stream is closed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/utils.py", line 742, in wrapper
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/client.py", line 1508, in _handle_report
    await self._reconnect()
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/utils.py", line 742, in wrapper
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/client.py", line 1298, in _reconnect
    await self._ensure_connected(timeout=timeout)
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/client.py", line 1328, in _ensure_connected
    comm = await connect(
  File "/pip_packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 315, in connect
    await asyncio.sleep(backoff)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 655, in sleep
    return await future
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

Thanks as ever!

Answer (score 1):

Context managers are a good practice (I'd also say 'best practice', but not sure if that would be widely supported).

> If a context manager is the sole way to go, is it possible to call the relevant context manager directly without the with?

The relevant context manager functions are defined in `__enter__` and `__exit__`, but calling them directly is not a good practice.

> Do I have it right that the cluster should be closed before the client (since the latter would presumably be required to achieve the former)?

In general a given cluster could serve multiple clients, and so one typically would only open/close client connection, while the cluster start/shutdown would be governed by the relevant process. This should clarify the order/hierarchy. In cases where the cluster is created just for a specific purpose (so multiple client connections are not expected), it's still a good idea to follow this order and close the client first. This order is easiest to follow when using multiple context managers:

```py
from time import sleep

from distributed import Client, LocalCluster

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with LocalCluster() as cluster, Client(cluster) as client:
        futs = client.map(sleep, range(10))
        print(*client.gather(futs))  # will print None 10 times
```

In the above, to instantiate a `client`, one needs to have a `cluster` first.

While this answer doesn't answer directly the exceptions you mention, I would either try to find a reproducible example, or make sure I am running the latest dask version and use the context managers.

The fact that a third-party class does clean-up and it affects client/cluster logic is indicative of poor separation of concerns, so a more efficient solution is to address this problem.

Comment: Thank you very very much for this helpful and authoritative answer, so grateful. I do indeed have multiple client connections and the cluster is a (chargeable) resource on ECS so I also need cluster shutdown. I expect I have a race condition between the clients. Do you have any pointers and/or should I update my Q? Thanks again

Comment: I would highly recommend using Coiled for cloud+dask, they have a lot of useful functionality for managing costs/resources/etc. Another vendor is Saturn cloud, but I never tried their services.

Comment: Thank you - I'm afraid a buy scenario is not possible for me :(

Comment: I should have mentioned this also: https://github.com/dask/dask-cloudprovider