# How can I use a third-party context manager to run a custom-class's method?

Tags: python, object, with-statement, contextmanager

In python, I'd like to use a `with`-statement context manager when using a particular third-party package because their context manager will handle clean-up for me in a best-practice way.

Right now I have (say):

```py
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.open()

    def open(self):
        # Instantiate something *e.g.* open() a file

    def run(self):
        # Do some work *e.g.* read() from a filehandle

    def cleanup(self):
        # Clean everything up *e.g.* close() filehandle
```

This would then be called as

```py
my_obj = MyClass()
my_obj.open()
my_obj.run()
my_obj.cleanup()
```

I'd ideally like to do all this using a context manager referenced *within* the class (if possible). It's the `run()` method that needs the context here. I am not sure how to do this - here are some theoretical attempts:

Option 1:

```py
my_obj2=MyClass2()
with my_obj2.third_party_context_manager_method() as mcmm:
    my_obj2.run()
```

Option 2:

```py
my_obj3=MyClass3()
my_obj3.run_modified_containing_third_party_context_manager()
```

**Bonus:** Now, in fact I need a double context manager in this case - how on earth..?

**Please note:** The file open example is just an example! My case is somewhat more complicated but the idea is that if I can make it work for that I can achieve anything :)

**Another note:** The use case is a dask cluster/client cleanup scenario - REF: [How can I exit Dask cleanly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76312844/how-can-i-exit-dask-cleanly)

Comment: Where does the third-party context manager come in? I see where *your* context manager comes in, but not the third-party context manager.

Comment: What is the problem with writing such a context manager and returning it when `my_context_manager_method` is called?

Comment: Someone voted to close because of lacking detail and clarity - where am I lacking either..? I thought I had done quite well there :(

Comment: @user2357112 That is exactly the point - how do I call my `run()` method inside a `with third_party_context_manager:` statement?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don't follow - if that's the start of an answer I'd love to see one. Thanks

Comment: I voted to close (and downvoted) because you needed more than 20 minutes to react on the question of @user2357112 (and mine).

Comment: I don't understand the problem yet. You wrote to user2357112: "how do I call my `run()` method inside a `with third_party_context_manager:`statement?" But what is the problem with writing `with third_party_context_manager: my_obj.run()`?

Comment: I don't see the relationship between reaction and time - is there a rule about that? I was actually just away from my desk I'm afraid. Sorry to say, I think you are being a bit mean :( In terms of your question: I would like the `third_party_context_manager` to be contained within `my_obj`.

Comment: The question was contradictory (own context manager, third party context manager) and (is yet) hard to understand. In such cases I write a comment (if not someone else did already) and wait at least 10 minutes for a reply before I vote. Many people here don't wait that long (or don't ask for clarification at all) before voting to close.

Comment: What exactly means "`third_party_context_manager` to be contained within `my_obj`".? Should `my_obj` hold a reference to the context manager class (or factory function) or should the code of the context manager be contained in the code of `MyClass`?

Comment: The code of the context manager should be contained within the code of MyClass (option 2 that I give), or it should hold a reference to the third-party context manager (option 1 that I give). Is that enough for you to go on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have any limitations you have but here's a couple of basic ideas.

With a decorator:

```
def with_context(cm):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with cm:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class MyClass(object):
    ...
    @with_context(ThirdPartyCM)
    def run(self):
        # Do some work *e.g.* read() from a filehandle
```

Then just the simple way:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...

    def _run(self):
        # Do some work *e.g.* read() from a filehandle

    def run(self):
        with ThirdPartyCM() as cm:
            self._run()
```

Alternatively you could inherit the 3rd party class if you needed it to be open for everything, but as you only need it open for `run`, I don't see why the above wouldn't work.